# How are the operations of the TeX tokenizer and engine interleaved?

Tags: token-lists

On p. 38 of [Knuth's *The TeXbook* (1996)](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf), a TeX system is broken down into two components: the "mouth" that "chews" the `.tex` manuscript and converts it to tokens, and the "stomach" that does the actual processing based on the token list it receives from the "mouth".

Here's the relevant excerpt.

[image: TeX's mouth and stomach]

What is unclear to me from this description is how the two parts are synchronized with each other.

Is the "stomach" activated only once the "mouth" has finished converting the entire manuscript to tokens, or are the activations of the "mouth" and the "stomach" interleaved?

If the latter is the case, how are they interleaved? Does the "mouth" halts after every single token, waiting for the stomach to process the token, before processing the rest of the manuscript, or does the "mouth" operate in bigger chunks, say reading and tokenizing an entire line of manuscript at a time?

Comment: Have you read chapter 1, "The Structure of the TeX Processor", of Victor Eijkhout's book [TeX by Topic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)?

Comment: From @Mico's reference (p.21), "For many purposes it is most convenient, and most insightful, to consider these four levels
of processing as happening after one another, each one accepting the completed output of
the previous level. In reality this is not true: all levels are simultaneously active, and there
is interaction between them."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: The quote you cited is at odds with David Carlisle's answer below, which implies that it can't be assumed that, systematically, an entire line is tokenized en masse and passed on to the next level, let alone the complete manuscript, as suggested by your quote.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger!

Comment: the quote matches what I said. It says that there is a simpler model that  you may find more convenient, but it is not true.

Comment: @Mico: In my opinion chapter 1 of Eijkhout's book is misleading. For instance section 1.3.1 *The process of expansion* (p. 23) implies that if a token is expandable, it is immediately expanded ("3. If the token is expandable, replace it by its expansion."). However, this is not the case. Consider, for instance, `\def\a{\b} \def\a{Hello, world!}`. If the second occurrence of the control sequence `\a` were immediately expanded, the result would be that the second `\def` would end up defining the macro `\b` instead of redefining `\a`.

Comment: @Mico: The question is not why I assume that TeX is in expansion mode at this stage, but rather why would you or any reader assume that there is even such a thing as "expansion mode" at this point in the text? Eijkenhout gives an algorithm. A short and simple algorithm. And the algorithm is incorrect as written. Of course one can always take an incorrect statement and make it correct by re-interpreting it and adding information, for instance if someone said that "2 + 2 = 5" and I said this was false, one could counter: "Clearly the statement was meant to be understood in negation mode."

Comment: @Mico: But this *is* the expansion algorithm, according to Ejkenhout. That's it. Section 1.3.1 titled *The process of expansion*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60874/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-mico).

Comment: @EvanAad - Upon re-reading your earlier comments, I've come to realize that you may not have grasped the full meaning of Eijkhout's statement that "If the token is expandable, replace it by its expansion." The problem with your supposed counter-example -- `\def\a{\b} \def\a{Hello, world!}` -- is that `\def` is *not* an expandable token but, rather, a so-called "primitive" directive. The `\def` directives are handled partly by the input processor (e.g., to determine how far one must scan ahead to determine the "name" of the macro) and partly by TeX's execution processor.

Comment: @EvanAad - I've deleted my earlier comments because I've come to realize that they weren't all that helpful as they failed to address the main point made above, viz., that not all token directives are expandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an entire line was tokenized in advance you would not be able to change tokenization mid-line

In

```
\@zzz   \makeatletter \@zzz
```

The first "word" is tokenized as the four tokens `\@` `z` `z` `z`

then after the expansion of `\makeatletter` causes the assignment (stomach operation) of the catcode of `@` the second word is tokenized as the single token `\@zzz`

Basically each stomach operation will require some input and then TeX expands tokens just until that one operation has enough input, then it starts processing the remaining input.

so if you have

```
\def\zz{12}\def\zzz{ \zzzz}\def\zzzz{hello}
\count0=\zz\zzz
```

then when the assignment for `\count0` is started in the stomach tex will expand tokens until it has a valid count, so first `\zz` expands to 12, which isn't a completed number so then `\zzz` expands to `\zzzz` so the count is completed at the space so `\zzzz` is not expanded and TeX acts as if the input had been

```
\count0=12 \zzzz
```

Then after the assignment processing will continue, expanding `\zzzz` (unless processing order has been changed with `\afterassignment`).

So here `\count0=\zz\zzz` is processed as start of assignment, expand `\zz` expand `\zzz` finish assignment, expand `\zzzz`.

Conversely if the space had not been there, but in `\zzzz`:

```
\def\zz{12}\def\zzz{\zzzz}\def\zzzz{ hello}
\count0=\zz\zzz
```

then after expanding `\zzz` the assignment would still not be complete so `\zzzz` would in this case be expanded before the assignment happens and TeX would act as if the input were

```
\count0=12 hello
```

and the order of operation is

`\count0=\zz\zzz` is processed as start of assignment, expand `\zz` expand `\zzz` expand `\zzzz`, finish assignment.

Comment: So is it safe to take the view that the mouth halts after every token and passes it on to the stomach for digesting, after which the stomach halts and returns control to the mouth, where both mouth and stomach can maintain a persistent state from one activation to another? I find the image of switching from mouth to stomach at the deterministic rate of one token at a time easier to grapple with than the non-deterministic "TeX expands tokens just until that one operation has enough input".

Comment: @EvanAad it's less true to take that view, whether it is safe depends on your assessment of risk. (consider `\edef` or `\write` where you necessarily get a sequence of pure expansion, with no intervening assignments)

Comment: By 'safe' I meant as follows. Suppose I take the point of view of *one token at a time + persistent state*. Will the set of true statements that can be said about TeX based on the specifications given in the TeXbook (rather than on the actual implementation in the source code) be the same as the set of true statements assuming the point of view that "TeX expands tokens just until that one operation has enough input"?

Comment: I'm sorry, David, but I fell asleep before reading to the end of your answer.  I think there must have been a subliminal message in your coding to do so, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes sorry. I will return to my usual one liners in future, you can return to sleeping over egreg's novellas

Comment: It wasn't the length of the answer, it was all those `\zzzzz`s.  I felt like I was in a lumber mill.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I had considered the possibility that that was what you meant, but rejected it: what other command names would be possible?

Comment: Oh, I forgot... in CarlisLaTex, `z` is the only `\catcode=11` token.